# How how to call react function from html stored in database

Tags: reactjs, jsx

so the case is i have a react file which is stored in the database the structure is like below i inserted the react function inside the file to be able to call the above react function which has been generated from the database

```
      component: `
        <nav onClick={() => this.testFunction()} name="{__name}" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light component" style="{__style}" data-component="{__data}">
          <div class="menu-edit">
            <div>
              <a href="#">
                <i class="bi-gear"></i>
                <span>Setting</span>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">{__name}</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
              <ul class="navbar-nav">
                {__menu}
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      `
```

Comment: That's a quite unusual use case for jsx. Why do you want to store executable code in the database? This adds lots of complexity, renders existing tooling useless (version control, error handling, debugging, building/bundling), and seems vulnerable to code injection exploits.

Comment: I think that this is a terrible idea. Why did you decided to implement it like this? What happens if you reference some function that does not exist inside of the react component? How do you prevent code injection? Do you want to render at build time or at runtime? What are you aiming to do? Is there a better way to implement this?

Comment: i'm faced with a website builder where i have to build a compiler code to store in a database i made my own compiler to handle injection and for the frontend any suggestions